# Matching columns containing aggregates with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to design a regular expression to identify certain columns in the string. This is the input string -

```
GENDER = Y OR (SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) > 100 AND SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) < 600)
```

I'm trying to match `SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT)` from above string.

This is the regex I've tried:

```
SUM([a-zA-Z])
```

But its not able to match properly. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my regex here. Thanks in advance.

Sample Code:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("SUM([a-zA-Z])").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    input.add(m.group(1));
```

Comment: Your regex does not match the character '_' that is present in your example input. Also, you need a quantifier for your character class.

Comment: That is, `Pattern.compile("SUM\\([^()]+\\)").matcher(str)` and then `input.add(m.group(0));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Many thanks for your suggestion. Your logic with negation is much better than what I was trying. If you'd like, please put this down as an answer so that I can check-mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
String str = "GENDER = Y OR (SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) > 100 AND SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) < 600)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("SUM\\([^()]+\\)").matcher(str);
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    input.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(input);
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/EQ3N3n). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OFi2Kz/1), too. It matches

- `SUM\(` - a `SUM(` string
- `[^()]+` - one or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Note that I am using `matcher.group()` in the code to get the full match since there is no capturing group in the pattern (thus, you can't use `matcher.group(1)` here).